# How to Change Content of Button if it is a child of a grid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

> *I want to change content of button1 on click event of button2 . But not able to get the object of grid's child Button class which is in List<> UiList.*
>   Please Guide me in getting the right approach to look it and solve it . And also guide that if the object is build in runtime then how to access it ?

```
public partial class MainPage :   PhoneApplicationPage

  {  

    List<Grid> UIList = new List<Grid>();
    Grid objGrid1 = null;
    Button objButton1 = null;
    Button objButton2 = null;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createGrid1("grid1");
        createButton2("Button2");
    }


    public void createGrid1(string x)
    {
        objGrid1 = new Grid();
        objGrid1.Height = 100;
        objGrid1.Name = x;
        objGrid1.Width = 200;
        objGrid1.Margin = new Thickness(100, 100, 0, 0);
        objGrid1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        objGrid1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        objGrid1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);            
        createButton1("changename");

    }
    public void createButton1(string _name)
    {
        objButton1 = new Button();
        objButton1.Height = 90;
        objButton1.Name = _name;
        objButton1.Content="Button1";
        objButton1.FontSize = 20;
        objButton1.Width = 190;            
        objButton1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        objButton1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        objButton1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        objButton1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        objGrid1.Children.Add(objButton1);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(objGrid1);
        UIList.Add(objGrid1);

    }
    public void createButton2(string _name)
    {
        objButton2 = new Button();
        objButton2.Margin = new Thickness(240, 300, 0, 0);
        objButton2.Name = _name;
        objButton2.Height = 90;
        objButton2.Content = "Button2";
        objButton2.FontSize = 20;
        objButton2.Width = 190;
        objButton2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        objButton2.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        objButton2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        objButton2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(objButton2);
        objButton2.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                int c = UIList.ElementAt(0).Children.Count;
                if (c == 1)
                {
                    //logic to change content of Button1 on click of Button2
                }
            };

    }

}
```

Comment: Does `objButton1.Content = "SomthingElse"` not work?

Comment: it does work but if your object is build in Runtime then how to access that ..

Comment: Then create a field in your class and store the button there when you create it?

Comment: But the grid which was also created in runtime is not update itself .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cannot just keep a reference to the created control, such as in a class field, you can iterate through the [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and find the desired Button. If there are multiple buttons, you can differentiate them using the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

Once you find it, change the contents of the button using the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property, as discussed in the contents above.